# Changing $location from $rootScope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a web app that is using AngularJS. I have two functions. One is declared on the `$rootScope`, the other is declared on the `$scope`. The code looks like this:

**app.js**

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.settings_Click = function() {
    $console.log('clicked in root scope.');
    $location.url('/user/settings');
  };
});
```

**viewController.js**

```
app.controller('ViewController', function($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
  $scope.settings_Click = function() {
    $console.log('clicked in local scope.');
    $location.url('/user/settings');
  };
});
```

While both of these functions get called, only the latter redirects to the `/user/settings` view. I can't figure out why. If I trigger the `settings_Click` event that uses `$rootScope`, no error is thrown. The user is redirected to the first page in the app instead of the settings page. Yet, the redirect is the same as the one in `$scope`.

Why would the redirect behave differently between `$scope` and `$rootScope`?

Comment: I didnt get the question

Comment: The first code block does not work. The second one does. The difference, as far as I know, is $rootScope vs $scope.

Comment: I've no idea what is the different at the moment, but you may need to use `$location.path()` instead of `$location.url()`.

Comment: Thank you for trying. However, using $location.path() did not work either.

Comment: but $console.log('clicked in local scope.'); working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a problem with redefining your functions - I forget the term, but as all functions defined in `$rootScope` are available in `$scope` your are probably screwing up the original `$rootScope` version.

For example, a function defined here in `$rootScope` like this:

```
$rootScope.hi = function() {
    console.log('hi');
}
```

is available in `$scope` like this:

```
$scope.hi();
```

You can either totally leave out the `$scope` version or rename it. I think this will fix your issue.